# Beginner to c# having issues with CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm rather new to coding in C# and am trying to teach myself more.
I've been trying to work on a simple rpg with stats from levels in RPG and have gotten stuck with trying to apply the damage to an enemy based on my characters stats.

When I thought I had solved the issue by splitting my stats script for the player into a second one for the enemy units, I unfortunately ran into the issue where the left-hand side of the assignment needing to be a variable property or indexer, and no matter how much I search for solutions I'm stumped. Would anyone be able to take a look at my scripts and point out any glaring errors I've made?

Please and thank you!

```
   public void TakePhysicalDamage()
    {
    defaultStats.GetPhysicalDamage()-= armor; //This is the offending line
    physicalDamage = Mathf.Clamp(physicalDamage, 0, int.MaxValue);
    health -= (int)Math.Round(physicalDamage);   
    
    if(health <= 0)
        {
        health = 0;
        Die();
    }
}
void Die()
{
    {
        playerLevel.AddExperience(experience_reward);
    }
    Destroy(gameObject);
}

}
```

Here is the playerstats (defaultstats) script just for reference where I'm trying to get the physical damage from

[SerializeField] float strength = 5f;
[SerializeField] float physicalDamage = 5f;

```
  public float GetPhysicalDamage()
  {
    return physicalDamage += strength;
  }
```

Sorry if this seems super basic, but please take a look if you're bored!

Comment: You may need to look up the proper (non Java) way to code a property

Comment: By the way, we cannot tell where line 126 is. Please add a comment to the offending line

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thanks for the tip regarding coding a property! I was just doing what I'd picked up in tutorials. I added a comment to the offending line

Comment: `defaultStats.GetPhysicalDamage()-= armor;` is the offending line and `defaultStats.GetPhysicalDamage()` is not a variable, it is a method call. As such you cannot assign a result to it. you may wanmt to assign the result of this method call to a new variable and the subtract `armor` from that variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to modify a function:

```
defaultStats.GetPhysicalDamage()-= armor;
```

but you can't, because `GetPhysicalDamage` only returns damage, it isn't setup as a property that would allow you to modify it (and also don't do that!)

```
public float GetPhysicalDamage()
{
  return physicalDamage += strength;
}
```

Instead, it looks like you have a variable `physicalDamage` that you should be using instead, like:

```
public void TakePhysicalDamage()
{
    physicalDamage = defaultStats.GetPhysicalDamage() - armor; //This is the offending line
    physicalDamage = Mathf.Clamp(physicalDamage, 0, int.MaxValue);
    health -= (int)Math.Round(physicalDamage);   
    
    if(health <= 0)
    {
        health = 0;
        Die();
    }
}
```

Actually, on closer review, I think you're probably not doing what you think you're doing. It looks like `physicalDamage` is supposed to be the base damage you're doing, but when you have a line like the following from `GetPhysicalDamage()`:

```
return physicalDamage += strength;
```

if `physicalDamage` is 5 and `strength` is 5, then the first time you call `GetPhysicalDamage()` you get 10. BUT what you're doing is **adding** the strength to physical damage and **storing** that value as the new physical damage with the `+=` operator, such that the next time you call `GetPhysicalDamage()` the `physicalDamage` variable is now 10 (from the previous call) and now it returns 15. Then 20, 25, etc.

I think what you want instead is just the sum of physicalDamage and strength, like:

```
return physicalDamage + strength;
```

But if this is the case then I think the variable name `physicalDamage` is misleading. I would personally prefer something like `basePhysicalDamage` and then you can have a property like:

```
public int PhysicalDamage => basePhysicalDamage + strength;
```

I would especially recommend doing this because later in your code, where you're having the issues now, you are modifying the `physicalDamage` variable on lines like:

```
physicalDamage = Mathf.Clamp(physicalDamage, 0, int.MaxValue);
```

This is also confused because it looks like you're trying to `GetPhysicalDamage` and modify that with `armor`, but when you call `GetPhysicalDamage` and `armor` you're getting them from the same (local) source, so it would be either the player's physical damage dealt to themselves with the player's armor, or it would be the mob's physical damage dealt to themselves with their armor.

I would pass the damage as an argument so that you can send damage from one thing to another, like:

```
public void TakePhysicalDamage(int damage)
{
    damage -= armor;
    damage = Mathf.Clamp(damage, 0, int.MaxValue);
    health -= (int)Math.Round(damage);
    if(health <= 0)
    {
        health = 0;
        Die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer! I'd actually already ran into the issue where the armor was subtracting from the damage and was trying to solve it by splitting the scripts.

I've attempted to implement your suggestions to the best of my ability, but now the "Math" in Math.Round doesn't exist in the current context.

(I have damage as a float in case I want to multiply instead of add

public void TakePhysicalDamage(float damage)  
    {  
    damage -= armor;  
    damage = Mathf.Clamp(damage, 0, int.MaxValue);  
    health -= (int)Math.Round(damage);

Comment: @Dogman25 - When you have something that `doesn't exist in the current context` it's probably a missing namespace, and I think that's also part of the error text ("are you missing a ....?"). For [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0), it's from the `System` namespace, so you should either qualify that call with `System.Math.Round` or add a `using System;` statement at the top of the script.

Comment: Ah, I must have failed to add system into the enemy script when repopulating it. Thanks for the kind answers! I'll keep trying to press on with the new knowledge you've given me!